# why the callback of functions from an array are no executed?

Tags: node.js

I am kind of new at nodejs. I create a array of functions and I can't make my callback of the functions be executed. Can anybody help me?

```
'using strict'

const tasks = [];
tasks.push(function (callback)  {
    console.log('Hi.. executing task 1'); 
    return callback;
});
tasks.push(function (callback) { 
    console.log('Hi.. executing task 2'); 
    return callback; 
});
tasks.push(function (callback) { 
    console.log('Hi.. executing task 3'); 
    return callback; 
});

function iterate(index, callback) {
    if (index === tasks.length) {
        return callback();
    }
    const task = tasks[index];
    task(function () {
        console.log('Hi.. executing task callback'); 
        //the line, I really want to include in here is
        //   iterate(index + 1, callback);
     });
    iterate(index + 1, callback);
}
function finish() {
    console.log('Execution complete');
}
iterate(0, finish);
```

The console shows

Hi.. executing task 1

Hi.. executing task 2

Hi.. executing task 3

Execution complete

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it carefully, you are not executing the callback, instead you're just returning it. So you can either

```
    cbFunc = task(function () {
        console.log('Hi.. executing task callback'); 
        //the line, I really want to include in here is
        //   iterate(index + 1, callback);
     });
    cbFunc();
```

or

```
tasks.push(function (callback)  {
    console.log('Hi.. executing task 1'); 
    return callback();
});
```

Comment: yes.. I figure it out ... sorry....I ashamed... what a stupid rookie error.